# cannot import numpy when script located in a subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a folder structure like so

```
root/        
    A0/
        A1/
    B0/
        B1/
```

Lets say I have a file called test.py. In it, I import numpy like so

```
import numpy as np
```

That is all that is contained in the file. This works without issue when it is located in root, subfolder A0,A1,B0 but raises an error in subfolder B1. Is error raised is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pose/utils/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 187, in <module>
    from .testing import Tester
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 6, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/home/adrian/Projects/lpr-pose-estimation/pose/utils/logging.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pose.utils.utils import mkdir_if_missing
  File "/home/adrian/Projects/lpr-pose-estimation/pose/utils/utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import imresize
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/misc/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    from scipy.interpolate._pade import pade as _pade
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
    from .interpolate import *
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .interpnd import _ndim_coords_from_arrays
  File "interpnd.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from .kdtree import *
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py", line 8, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 230, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._numpy_compat import broadcast_to
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_numpy_compat.py", line 16, in <module>
    _assert_warns = np.testing.assert_warns
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'
```

Importing as modules (e.g cv2) also leads to errors, but only wrt to numpy:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pose/utils/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
  File "/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

What may be the cause of such an error?

Comment: It seems you have your own module `logging` which is imported instead of the expected one from standard library. This has the effect that `np.testing` is used while its initialization is yet in progress.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, this seems to have been the cause of the error. It works now, thanks. If you have the time, could you flesh out your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your start script is located in `.../pose/utils` then every absolute import looks for modules there, too. This directory contains a module named `logging` (like the one in the standard library).

During the initialization of the `numpy` package (executing its `__init__.py`) and before `numpy.testing` is available the usual chain of imports happens (as can be seen in the traceback) which leads to the wrong `logging` module which in turn leads to import of `_numpy_compat` which tries to access `numpy.testing` too early.

To avoid this circular import problem you can either rename your `logging` module or move the start script to another directory.